# Given a polynomial $p$, then $\forall K>0$, $\exists r_k$ such that $|t|\geq r_k \Rightarrow |p(t)|\geq K$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, proof-verification, induction

Let $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be polynomial $p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t+ \cdots + a_n t^n $ $(a_n \neq 0)$.

I'd like to prove the following statement by induction: $\forall K>0$  there exists $r_k$ such that $|t|\geq r_k \Rightarrow |p(t)|\geq K$.

**My attempt**

**Base case:** For $n=1$, we have $p(t) = a_1t + a_0 $, $a_1 \neq 0$ and:
$|p(t)| = | a_1t + a_0| \geq  |a_1||t| - |a_0| \geq K \iff |t| \geq \frac{K+|a_0|}{|a_1|}$

Take $r_k = \frac{K+|a_0|}{|a_1|} $ and we have  $|t|\geq r_k \Rightarrow |p(t)|\geq K$.
Since $K$ was arbitrary, the statement holds for $n=1$.

**Inductive step:**
Assume that the statement holds for $n-1$.

It means that given $ q(t) = a_0 + a_1 t+ \cdots + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} $,
$(a_{n-1} \neq 0)$ and $K>0$,   there exists $r_k $ such that $|t| \geq r_k \Rightarrow|q(t)| \geq K$.

Given $p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t+ \cdots + a_n t^n $, $(a_n \neq 0)$ , we can write :
$p(t) = a_0 + t(a_1 + \cdots + a_n t^{n-1}) = a_0 + tq(t)$ .

Note that $q(t) = a_1 + \cdots + a_n t^{n-1} $ satisfies the induction hypothesis.

Observe that:

$$|p(t)| \geq |t||q(t)| -|a_0| \geq K \iff |t||q(t)| \geq K + |a_0|  $$

Since $q(t)$ satisfies the induction hypothesis, there exists $r_1$ such that $|t|\geq r_1 \Rightarrow |q(t)| \geq \sqrt{K+|a_0|} $.

$r(t) = t$ also  satisfies the induction hypothesis then there exists $r_2$ such that $|t|\geq r_2 \Rightarrow |r(t)| \geq \sqrt{K+|a_0|}$.

Take $r_k  = \max \{r_1,r_2\}$.

Then  $|t|\geq r_k \Rightarrow |p(t)|\geq K$. Thus the statement holds for $n$.

Am I right?

Comment: I checked through your inductive proof. It is nice, and I am confident that it is correct. I like the way you decompose the polynomial and factor out the $t$. That is the key step. Le Van Tu gives the result at a glance using the fundamental theorem of algebra, which is really nice. It is great to see both approaches complementing each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your attempt is correct. I suppose another way that use the Theorem Fundamental of Algebra, which implies that every real polynomial can be written by product of $(x-a)$ and $(x^2-ax+b)$. These polynomials is obviously tend ver infinite when x tend ver infinite

Comment: Nice. Using the fundamental theorem shows this immediately.